# Set css property using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The goal is to amend all the `td` elements of class `mytable` to have css property `visibility:hidden`. the statement `$('.mytable td').css('visibility', 'hidden');` seems to have no effect, why?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.mytable td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.mytable td {
    border:1px solid;
    visibility:inline;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works if you include jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong in your code, you are missing jQuery library in your code. So add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for including jQuery library
`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mytable td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid;
  visibility: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code *does* work, but you forgot including jQuery on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.mytable td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.mytable td {
    border:1px solid;
    visibility:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Note that  there is also a `hide()` method which sets `display:none` your elements.

```
$('.mytable td').hide();
```

Comment: `hide()` is equivalent to `.css( "display", "none" )`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yes, I just thought it may help the user. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.mytable td').css('display', 'none');`

Comment: That's different bahaviour and doesn't explain OP issue anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to include the jQuery library:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.mytable td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.mytable td {
    border:1px solid;
    visibility:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.mytable td').css('display', 'none');
});
```